# Vuejs upload multiple image not working without cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to use this [plugin](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-upload-multiple-image-component-for-vuejs/) for upload multiple images with vue.js. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>vue-upload-multiple-image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-strictly-unique-vue-upload-multiple-image" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <vue-upload-multiple-image
                @upload-success="uploadImageSuccess"
                @before-remove="beforeRemove"
                @edit-image="editImage"
                @data-change="dataChange"
                :data-images="images"
                ></vue-upload-multiple-image>
        </div>
        <script src="./dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this code neither gives error nor output. But when I use this cdn it works.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to use it without the cdn?. Js file is there and I downloaded it from cdn.

Thanks

Comment: There should be no difference. Are you sure your script is in the folder that you are referencing in your `<script>`?

Comment: yes because when I click it in page source and I can see the code

Comment: Have you imported it? `import VueUploadMultipleImage from 'vue-upload-multiple-image'` and included it in `components: {VueUploadMultipleImage}`

Comment: Are you using a packet manager, or are you downloading it manually?

Comment: downloaded manually and think don't need to import since it work with cdn

Comment: What element is this app mounted on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the script should not normally change anything.

**Do you use the same version of the plugin?** To be sure, you can copy the content of the https://unpkg.com/vue-upload-multiple-image@1.0.2/dist/vue-upload-multiple-image.js into your file (right click, save as...).

**Is it added to the page?** Do you have a plugin like Adblock and does it inform you that it has blocked content? Open your network console and check that the file is downloaded correctly without error (you will see a line with the filename). Did you see the JS code from the network console when you click on the line (to prevent bad serveur configuration)?.

To be sure, you can add something at the end of the script file :

```
let myTestVar = "JESuisLA";
```

And verify you can access to myTestVar on the console.